# how to hide / mask data-plyr-provider from html code

Tags: javascript, plyr.js

I am using plyr to play YouTube videos. I would like to hide the `data-plyr-provider` definition from the html file. It is always going to be YouTube.

Currently I am using this code

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="player" data-plyr-provider="youtube" data-plyr-embed-id="somegoogleid"></div>
</div>
<script src='https://web.con/124141/users/plyr/plyr.min.js'></script>
<script>
const player = new Plyr('#player', {});
// Expose player so it can be used from the console
window.player = player;
</script>
```

What I want to hide is the code in the red box [image: https://i.imgur.com/0BELK9V.png]

I was thinking that I can modify `plyr.min.js` I am using and hardcode the string YouTube but when looking into the code I am not able to do so. I mean I cannot find the right place.

The only reference of `data-plyr-provider` in the .js I found is this line

`attributes: { embed: { provider: "data-plyr-provider", id: "data-plyr-embed-id" } },`

Can some one help? Where to modify the code or if there is any other way how to hide `plyr.min.js`

Comment: You could get the full code (mostly inside dist) folder from https://github.com/sampotts/plyr instead of using the minified.js file. I don't get what you want to hide? Where is the plyr.min.js visible? Can you may add a print screen of what you want to hide?

Comment: How do you bundle your code? Do you use webpack?

Comment: @caramba I want to hide the text in the red box https://i.imgur.com/0BELK9V.png . The text from the html source.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure i really need to write this down here but there is no offical way to pass an attributes directly into `Plyr` constructor.

So what you can you fork it your own then change the lines like following:
on plyr.js inside src/js/plyr.js
close the lines: #201, #205
and add:

```js
this.provider = 'youtube'; // on line #202
```

In this way you can create Plyr's from "div" source.

iframe is gonna stay as it is. If you provide iframe it's gonna work as it is.

After all:

`npm run build`

Create your own build and then use the plyr.min.js from your dist folder with following:

```html
<div id="player" data-plyr-id="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SF0w2B6DNUE"></div>
```

```js
const player = new Plyr('#player');

// Expose player so it can be used from the console
window.player = player;
```

There you go. An un-offical way to create a plyr specs to youtube online with div creator =)

***Update #1:***

Just before changes, please checkout to last production build. It may gets broken when you just do it on master branch =)

**Update #2:**
So since you told me that you don't know how to do it, I'll try to explain.

So first thing first, please go visit https://github.com/sampotts/plyr

Copy the link from image:
[image]

After this;

- Open a terminal and your code path.
- type `git clone https://github.com/sampotts/plyr.git`
- Wait until it's finish and type `cd plyr`
- Install dependencies with `npm i`
- open the current directory with some IDE (can be vscode, sublime or whatever you use for coding.) (`code .` will open it with VSCode)

After that open the file from the next picture:

[image]

Go to line #202 and you wil see following:
[image]

On here if you look up you will see this part of code is actually for type `div` anyway. As you can see there you get the provider from the line #201:

`this.provider = this.media.getAttribute(this.config.attributes.embed.provider)`

So comment this line(#201) out and add the following to line #202

`this.provider = 'youtube';`

And also don't forget to comment line #204 which gives us to end result of:

[image]

After these changes, (I believe you have `node` installed)

- Save the changes you have made.
- Open the terminal again.
- checkout the last production build with `git checkout v3.6.2`
- add changes to git via `git add .`
- create a commit with `git commit -m "provider set to youtube only"`
- then build the code with `npm run build`

After these steps, you will have the builded code from your js and css files from `dist` folder.

Please Backup your js files before doing following:

- Copy the required files from `dist/` folder to your server. (plyr.min.js and plyr.css)
- After everyting you have done,

You should be able to use everything from top.
[image]

I hope you could finally use it =)

***Update #3:***

Lets also add the dirty way of doing it from @Steve

@Radek, if you go this route, you should go through all the steps if you have time, but if you're looking for something quick and dirty, you can search plyr.min.js for

`this.provider=this.media.getAttribute(this.config.attributes.embed.provider),this.media.removeAttribute(this.config.attributes.embed.provider)`

and replacing it with

`this.provider='youtube'`

Comment: It is not good enough just to add the #202 line?  Do I have to run `mnp run build`? And the line to be added inside this function `function _defineProperty$1(e, t, n) {` ?

Comment: well Radek, first you need to clone the repository from github to your local envoirement. And add src/js/plyr.js#202 and then build =)

Comment: right now I am using only plyr.min.js and plyr.css on my website. And it works.
I tried to update plyr.js and uploaded to my site and used this one and the video does not even load. How is that if I use only one js file?

Comment: You can still use only plyr.min.js and plyr.css but after you build on your own. Do you know how to clone a repo, make changes and build with those changes?

Comment: No, I do not know. I also did not understand you comment about iframe.

Comment: I've updated the thread for you. Hope u can manage it after all =)

Comment: thank you so much. I will need some time to go through is and learn all the stuff

Comment: Sure please do let me know if you stuck some where, but everything i wrote is actually findable online Bdw I would be feel nice to this solution to mark as an answer :)) Good luck.

Comment: @Radek, if you go this route, you should go through all the steps if you have time, but if you're looking for something quick and dirty, you can search [plyr.min.js](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sampotts/plyr/master/dist/plyr.min.js) for `this.provider=this.media.getAttribute(this.config.attributes.embed.provider),this.media.removeAttribute(this.config.attributes.embed.provider)` and replacing it with `this.provider='youtube'`

Comment: thank you @Steve, this is exactly what I was looking for. Why do I have to go through all the steps if your solution does exactly what I want? It works.

Comment: @Radek, the more lengthy process is considered better practice, as it helps keep track of changes, helps debugging if anything goes wrong, or makes it easier to suggest changes to the author of `plyr.js`. Also if you ever want to update `plyr.min.js`, it can make things easier. But if you only need to do it once, need it done quickly, and are confident nothing will go wrong, editing the minified file might work out for you

Comment: @Steve, would you be able to help me to do the same with `data-plyr-embed-id` ?

Comment: But when you do with `data-plyr-embed-id` you could only be able to do one video with all script Be aware of that :)

Comment: I thought I would somehow encrypt youtube ID, use it in `data-plyr-embed-id` and decrypt it back in plyr.js